# Optic Fiber Gyroscope Within Its Frame

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, fiber-optics, gyroscopes

I understand why the fiber optic gyroscope works as well the calculations for the time discrepancy between the beams travel time, but only as observed from out side the ring, "watching" it spin.

But if I will drive a car and put it next to me, we will both be on the same frame of reference and I would not observe the ring rotating at all hence it should indicate 0 rate of rotation. I assume it will indicate the car's rotation. But if it does, shouldn't it indicate outside of the car the rotation rate of earth?
I am really confused please help me

Comment: I think you don't need to invoke relativity here (at least for the basic idea), and doing so may be confusing you more than helping. Imagine doing the same experiment with an apparatus that shoots golf balls around a ring, and measures which ball arrives first.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to agree with me: "At non-relativistic speeds, the Sagnac effect is a simple consequence of the source independence of the speed of light. In other words, the Sagnac experiment does not distinguish between pre-relativistic physics and relativistic physics." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_laser_gyroscope

Comment: (A key insight here is that relativity says a lot of things about _inertial_ frames being equivalent to each other, but a rotating frame is _not_ inertial.)

Comment: Shooting golf balls isn't equivalent since they will gain the velocity of the rotation which will cancel out with the movement of the detector, I calculated it. It Works because the light doesn't change its velocity by "emitting from a moving train" so to speak. But I do agree with the acceleration claim. I thought about that during the car acceleration the ring will take time to catch up and in the mean time won't be in the same frame. But if it is so, the gyro will only indicate when the angular rotation is changing, and when it is constant it will indicate 0 angular velocity. Is that true?

Comment: Hm, you're right -- my golf ball machine can only detect angular acceleration, not angular velocity. But as you say, it fails because the golf balls pick up extra velocity from the launcher's motion, and obviously light can't pick up extra velocity from the launcher in the same way (because the speed of light is constant.) Still, it doesn't have the same intuitive appeal at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer:
I will first give a link to an article that - as I see it - is in depth of understanding way ahead of any other discussion of the Sagnac effect.

Then I will discuss the fiber optic gyroscope.

Then I will discuss the ring laser interferometry implementation of rotation sensing, whose operating principle I regard as the most interesting instance of Sagnac effect manifestation.

**Article**

Olaf Wucknitz, 2004 [Sagnac effect, twin paradox and space-time topology](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0403111)

**Fiber optic gyroscope**

[image: Schematic representation of Sagnac interferometer]

The image is one that I uploaded to Wikipedia back when I started the Wikipedia article about the Sagnac effect (I no longer maintain that article, much has been addded)

Compare the setup depicted in the image with the Michelson-Morley interferometer setup. Many of the components are the same, positioned in the same arrangement. The essential difference is that in a Michelson-Morley interferometer the light does not travel around a loop. The feature that makes the setup depicted in the image a Sagnac interferometer is that the light is traveling around a *loop*.

As we know, the Michelson-Morley experiment yielded a null-result.

What is observed in the case of a Sagnac interferometer:
First the interferometer is calibrated. One way to calibrate would be to compare with a mechanical gyroscope.

However, in most cases it is *change* of angular velocity that is of interest. Then it is not necessary to account for the Earth's rotation. The state of being stationary relative to the Earth can be taken as zero state.

At the half silvered mirror the incoming beam of light is split in components, one component traveling clockwise around the loop, the other component traveling counter-clockwise.

When the Sagnac interferometer is rotating with an angular velocity relative to the zero state the interference pattern that is obtained is shifted with respect to the zero state interference pattern. The shift is there because compared to the zero state the clockwise and counter-clockwise light is traveling a different distance around the loop. (I will discuss this in more detail in the next section of this answer, in the discussion of the ring laser interferometer setup.)

I want to emphasize that it is possible to monitor the Earths rotation with a Sagnac interferometer. But as mentioned, that requires calibration against a reference of true zero rotation.

A mechanical gyroscope is a source of reference of zero rotation. Once a mechanical gyroscope has been spun up it will remain in the same orientation. (It is very tricky though; friction in the gimbal mount bearings will cause the mechanical gyroscope to drift. To mitigate tendency to drift the friction in the gimbal mount bearings has to be very, very small.)

A Sagnac interferometer setup can be used to monitor the Earth's rotation, but only when calibrated against a reference of zero rotation. But if a reference of zero rotation is necessary anyway it is simpler to measure the Earth's rotation against that reference directly.

Sagnac interferometer in a car

The Sagnac interferometer read out will allow you to tell whether the car is maintaining orientation, or is going around a corner. When the car keeps heading in the same direction the interference pattern remains the same. During change of orientation the interference pattern is shifted relative to the interference pattern when maintaining orientation.

**Ring laser interferometer**

The geologic observatory in Wettzell in Germany had a webpage about their ring laser setup. That page is gone now; the Internet Archive has a record of the page: [Large Laser Gyroscopes for Monitoring Earth Rotation](https://web.archive.org/web/20220814193834/http://www.fs.wettzell.de/LKREISEL/G/LaserGyros.html)

A ring laser gyroscope is the more interesting instance, in my opinion, because a ring laser gyroscope does not require calibration against an external reference.

[image: Schematic representation of a ring laser setup]

In a Sagnac interferometer the effect that is observabie is a phase shift.

With a ring laser interferometer setup the type of interference pattern that is obtained is a beat frequency. The beat frequency is zero if and only if the ring laser interferometer is not rotating.

When the ring laser interferometer is rotating the frequency of the beat frequency is proportional to the angular velocity.

**Operating principle**

[image: Schematic representation of counter-propagating photons]

The animation above illustrates the operating principle of ring laser interferometry.

The same reasoning also applies on larger scales. For instance, the synchronization procedures of the GPS system take the Sagnac effect into account.

To illustrate the operating principle I will use the following thought demonstration:
A number of time keeping stations are located at equal distance along the Equator. Timing pulses are relayed from station to station, both clockwise and counterclockwise.

In the animation the grey dots can regarded as representing 4 time-keeping stations, spaced equally along the Equator.

The colored dots represent pulses of electromagnetic energy. Pulses are received and upon arrival relayed to the next station. The procedure is to adjust the timing of sending the pulses such that the set of clockwise propagating pulses is at equal intervals of time apart (as recorded by the time-keeping stations), and that the set of counterclockwise propagating pulses is at equal time-intervals apart (as recorded by the time-keeping stations).

Notice especially that the information is going around in a loop. Each pulse of timing information keeps propagating around the loop.

The time-keeping stations are co-rotating with the Earth. As depicted in the animation: the co-propagating pulses have to travel a longer distance from relay to relay than the counter-propagating pulses.

This difference in distance traveled has a corresponding time difference.

Notice especially that in the animation the clockwise and counter-clockwise propagating colored dots have the same speed. The points where the blue dots and red dots cross each other do not shift because the colored dots are all propagating at the same speed.

As a matter of principle: the speed of light is the same in all directions. This principle of uniformity of the speed of light extends to the loop topology depicted in the animation. All the way around the loop the speed of light is the same.

Because of that the time-keeping stations (the grey dots) can set up a procedure that allows them to infer what their angular velocity is.

**Relativity of simultaneity**

If a group of time keeping stations is arranged such that there isn't a closed loop then the only way to keep timing signals going is to have the outermost stations send the signals back, effectively acting as reflecting mirrors.

Clearly, when a group of time-keeping stations is arranged along a straight line then any synchronization procedure will be subject to relativity of simultaneity.

However, in the case of a loop topology information can keep propagating around the loop indefinitely.